# Cannot figure out how to calculate radius of the circle in the given code

Tags: c++

I need to calculate the radius of the circle in the code.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Circle {

float radius;
const float PI=3.14;

public:
Circle(float radius){

    }
    Circle getRadius()
    {
        return radius;
    }
    Circle setRadius(float radius)
    {
        this->radius = radius / PI;
        return radius;
    }
    
    float Area()
    {
        return radius*radius*PI;
    }
    
    float Perimeter()
    {
    
        return 2*radius*PI;
    }
    int equal()
    {
        return Area()==Perimeter();
    
    }

};
int main() {
float r;

    cin >> r;
    Circle c(r);
    cout << c.Perimeter() << endl;
    cout << c.Area() << endl;
    cout << c.equal() <<endl;
    
    
    return 0;

}
```

i tried to use pointers but i cannot figure it out.

Comment: Calculate the radius from what exactly? What does `r` represent?

Comment: Sit down with your [Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) and discuss ways in which using pointers could assist you in solving this problem.

Comment: The r represents the radius above

Comment: Your constructor doesn't set radius ?

Comment: `The r represents the radius above` So you want to _calculate_ the radius using the radius? What?

Comment: Im new to programming so if you can answer in ways i could understand you it would be great

Comment: Regarding: `Circle(float radius){ }` a parameter with the same name as a member variable is not that member variable. It [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the member variable, effectively replacing it unless you know where to look. Passing a value into a variable named `radius` will not change the value of another variable named `radius`.

Comment: @IdrisSelimi I think you forgot to assign the radius in your constructor. `Circle(float radius) : radius(radius){

    }`

Comment: The above comment demonstrates the use of the [Member Initializer List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor), one of the most important (and least-taught) features of the C++ programming language. All member variables and base classes are initialized before entering the body of the constructor. Afterward the best you can do is assign. If the member being initialized has no default constructor, can be called without parameters, the only way to initialize it is with the member initializer list.

Comment: That `setRadius` divides the argument `radius` by π in order to compute *the radius* looks very odd. That your setter and getter both return a `Circle` is also odd. (Not that you ever use those functions, but anyway...)

Answer (score 2):

In

```cpp
Circle(float radius){

}
```

a parameter with the same name as a member variable is not that member variable. Instead, it [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the member variable, effectively replacing it unless you know where to look. Passing a value into a parameter named `radius` will not change the value of the member variable named `radius`, and this leaves the member `radius` uninitialized.

This means that

```cpp
float Perimeter()
{
    return 2*radius*PI;
}
```

and the other functions, excluding `setRadius`, operate on an uninitialized variable and the results will be undefined.

A possible solution is to ensure the member `radius` is initialized to the value of the parameter `radius`.

You cannot simply

```
Circle(float radius){
    radius = radius;
}
```

because there is only one `radius`, the member has been shadowed, so the parameter `radius` assigns its value to itself. This is legal code so it compiles, but often the compiler will issue a warning.

Instead use

```
Circle(float radius) : radius(radius) {

}
```

This makes use of the [Member Initializer List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor), one of the most important (and seemingly least-taught) features of the C++ programming language. It allows you to safely reuse the term `radius` because the first `radius` must be the member `radius`.

You could also

```
Circle(float radius)  {
    this->radius = radius;
}
```

to explicitly use the member `radius`, but for more complicated members this approach can be inefficient. All member variables and base classes are initialized before entering the body of the constructor. Afterward the best you can do is assign. This means the member will be default-initialized (if a default constructor exists; if it doesn't you must use the member initializer list), then a temporary variable must be constructed and this temporary is then assigned to the member. potentially a lot of extra work for no benefit.

Side note:

Keep an eye on the `this->radius = radius / PI;` in `setRadius`. It is unusual and probably a bug.